# GIF display issue while using WebView(The first frame is always there)

Tags: android, webview, gif

I have a webview and call mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
the content of test.html is just a IMG SRC=...
the webview can show the animation GIF, but the issue is the first frame of the GIF is always there while the GIF is animating.

What the problem is and how to fix?

Comment: What do you mean by `always there`? Have you tried another animated gif?

Comment: Yes, all GIFs have the same issue. And the behavior is, if I just loadUrl("file///android_asset/test.gif"), It is Ok, but if I wrap it in test.html, will face this issue. "always there" means the first frame is still showing though animation is animating...

Answer (score 1):

Animated gifs are not supported on all android phones. Animated gif support was only introduced in 2.2 and then only for high end phones that had the memory and CPU to handle them.

See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422 for more information about this.